# Does WNOHANG clean child resources

Tags: c, fork, parent-child

I am trying to understand how and does waitpid() using WNOHANG actually clean the resources of the child it's supposed to wait for?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() {

        printf("Hello from start\n");

        int pid;

        if((pid = fork()) == 0){
                printf("Hello from child: %d\n", getpid());
                printf("My parent PID is: %d\n", getppid());
        }else if(pid > 0){
                printf("Hello from parent: %d\n", getpid());
                int status;
                waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
        }else{
                perror("ERROR");
        }

        printf("Outside if statement, pid is: %d\n", getpid());


}
```

The output for child process for parent PID is: 1 meaning parent terminated and child was zombie passed to init process.

From what I understood WNOHANG in man description, it's supposed to return whether child process terminated at the time of testing it and let parent process continue on. I however thought that if parent was about to terminate before its child, it would wait for child to "clean it up". From this it seems that the parent just keeps on going and terminates without cleaning up.

What am I missing, and how to let parent continue its work but not let it terminate without waiting for child to terminate first?

Thanks!

Comment: "if parent was about to terminate before its child, it would wait for child to "clean it up"". No that's not true. There's no automatic wait. Parent needs to explicitly call one of the `wait` functions to reap the child. `WNOHANG` does not change that - it does not mean please check again later if child has not terminated at this time.

Comment: I see. What I meant was more focused on WNOHANG example where parent called waitpid(), then continued to run and only then reached its end. In that case since we already called waitpid() (with WNOHANG however) would parent wait for child or do we need additional wait?

Comment: Need additional wait.

Comment: Ok, so correct approach for creating children and letting parent run along them while cleaning up after they're done would be to place wait() right at the end of parent process before it terminates?

Comment: That's one common way. It depends on what your application behaviour needs to be. A shell for example may do a wait immediately if not running the command in the background and then continue after the wait returns.

Comment: If it is of interest to your application, suggest checking the `status` variable to determine why the `waitpid()` returned.  Because `wait()` and `waitpid()` return at a 'state' change of the child, not only when the child exits.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Outside if statement, pid is: %d\n", getpid())`  Both the parent and the child process AND the error path will execute this statement, so this statement will be executed once if `fork()` failed and twice for all other conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I however thought that if parent was about to terminate before its child, it would wait for child to "clean it up".

That is not the case. The parent won't wait. Children of a process that terminates get reparented to process 1, and they will automatically get reaped when they terminate.

> how to let parent continue its work but not let it terminate without waiting for child to terminate first?

```c
work();

int status;
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```